# Difficulties installing D-Link DWA-182 Drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless, adapter

When will Ubuntu have these drivers available for download? Seems the Drivers for **DWA-182** were released on 06/17/2014. They are for Linux! However, I just don't know how to install them and I have them download, extract but I can't get them to INSTALL.

I am newbie with Ubuntu and if someone could guide me on this will be great!

Answer (score 2):

There is a Linux Driver only for [hardware revision C](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-182) and it includes an install script `install.sh`. You can download the archive and try to install it.

Install the prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Unarchive it, then `cd` to the directory you extracted in and:

```
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: Please note that to compile this, you will first need to install prerequisites build-essential and linux-headers-generic.

Comment: I have the file download into the download file but I can't seem to get it too install ! Would someone please help me with the install from beginning to the END !!  This is the BOSS (wife) Computer .   Thanks You for anyone help ! It would be much appreciated !

Comment: I tested this out on Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela but I couldn't get it to work.  I detailed my pain and suffering here: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=213052

Answer (score 2):

Cornelius's answer didn't work for me on Linux Mint 17.2.

This did work though:

```
cd <somewhere reasonable>
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/
make clean
make
sudo make uninstall
sudo make install
```

Running the above commands probably requires some other packages.  These would probably be a good start:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install git
```

*Caution: I have no idea if this git repo is reliable, not full of spyware, etc.  Use at your own risk.*

All credit for this answer goes to [CFYves and his informative blog post](http://cfyves.com/2015/03/17/how-to-install-d-link-dwa-182-wireless-ac1200-dual-band-usb-adapter-on-linux-ubuntu/).  Thanks!