# Need Ubuntu Driver for D-Link

Tags: wireless, drivers

I am trying to switch to ubuntu. I am not good with anything yet. I downloaded ubuntu 11.1 ocelot... because it was compatible with the only internet access I have.

I downloaded this http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-182

I have a DWA-182 c1 wireless USB stick.

I put the driver on a stick and into ubuntu machine with no internet. I right clicked the install to properties and selected permissions>execute. I ran in the command prompt.

It is not working. If I can just get ubuntu and internet I can learn but in the meantime I just need internet.

I loaded ubuntu by making a usb stick.

Comment: duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/485102/d-link-dwa-182-drivers-for-linux

Comment: Ocelot is no longer supported, please update to a supported version, 12.04, 14.04, or 14.10

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do a `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`to make sure everything is up to date on your computer.